# Qt - Setting border-image to QPushButton makes it lose push effect

Tags: qt, user-interface, uibutton, qt-creator, qpushbutton

Searching around the internet I found a way to set up my own image for a QPushButton, with this line on style sheet:

```
border-image: url(:/Path/to/my/image.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
```

And the result has a nice appearance, but it loses the "push effect".

With the line

```
backgound-image: url(:/Path/to/my/image.jpg);
```

It keeps the push effect but the background image does not scale to the size of the button like with "border-image"

Is there a trick I haven't found yet to make it work with the border-image or I have to change the size of my .jpg image in order to have my button style correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a style sheet on all the button state.
Take a look on the Qt documentation [QPushButton stylesheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-a-qpushbutton-using-the-box-model)

Comment: Actually I was looking for some flag or property which I only had to check or activate, but I have no problem creating my own backgrounds and setting up the states. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, I found a way to do what I wanted, creating 2 different JPG images and setting each one to appear as the border-image in normal state and pressed state of the QPushButton, adding the following lines to the button's stylesheet:

```
QPushButton{ border-image:url(:/path/to/my/image.jpg); QPushButton:pressed{ border-image:url(:/path/to/my/image2.jpg); }
```

Works for me, I can say the problem is solved.